# Rotação Transform com Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity3d

Eu estou querendo desenvolver um jogo (iniciando os estudos agora), e estou tendo uma dificuldade:

Tenho um cenário que é basicamente um planeta e nesse planeta posso colocar objetos que irão "mirar" no jogador... eu estive vendo algumas formas e a mais interessante foi a função `LookAt(Transform)`, porém esse método rotaciona todos os eixos dos objetos que irão mirar o jogador. Eu gostaria de umas dicas sobre como eu posso girar esse objeto em apenas um eixo.
Independente do player pular, cair ou qualquer outra ação que o usuário faça de subir ou descer.

Alguém tem alguma dica de um tutorial ou alguma dúvida referente a isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supondo que você quer fixar o eixo y (isto é, fazer o seu objeto rotacionar ao longo do plano x-z apenas), basta você executar o `Transform::LookAt` passando como parâmetro um novo vetor em que as coordenadas x e z são do objeto-alvo e a coordenada y é do próprio objeto sendo rotacionado.

Nesse exemplo (em C#), suponha que esse script está anexado ao objeto sendo rotacionado (o canhão) e que há um outro objeto (o inimigo que o canhão deverá acertar) que foi linkado via editor à propriedade "enemy":

```csharp
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class RotateTowards : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform enemy;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        Vector3 vTarget = new Vector3 (enemy.position.x, transform.position.y, enemy.position.z);
        transform.LookAt(vTarget);

    }
}
```

Assim, a cada quadro do jogo, um novo vetor quase igual ao vetor de posição do inimigo (diferindo apenas no eixo y, em que se manteve a coordenada do canhão) é passado ao método `LookAt` (que irá rotacionar o canhão de forma a "apontar" para a posição no espaço dada).

Importante: Note que no Unity a convenção é que o eixo z aponta pra frente do objeto, por isso funções como o `LookAt` (traduzindo livremente: "olhar para") se baseiam nesse vetor para os cálculos. Se o seu objeto não estiver rotacionando como você deseja, você deverá modificá-lo de forma que a parte "da frente" fique apontada para o eixo z (talvez exista alguma forma de ajustar isso automaticamente no Unity, mas eu honestamente desconheço - pelo que eu sei isso é definido externamente na ferramenta 3D utilizada na modelagem do personagem ou objeto de jogo).

Esse exemplo que eu sugeri requer que o inimigo seja linkado ao canhão, mas num jogo real isso não costuma ser feito dessa forma porque existem diferentes inimigos. Nesse caso, a sugestão de utilizar um colisor é bacana, pois você pode receber eventos de colisão e rotacionar o canhão para o objeto (inimigo) que entrou na "area de ameaça". O melhor colisor para o seu caso parece ser mesmo [uma esfera](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/class-SphereCollider.html) centrada no canhão, cujo raio é configurado para definir a sua área de alcance.

Há também a possibilidade de se criar uma lista global de inimigos e verificar para cada um se eles se encontram aquém de em uma distância circular pre-definida, mas isso acaba sendo uma implementação própria de um teste de colisão.

Comment: Bom dia Luiz Vieira,
Cara... assim como o Chichila você me ajudou muito... a sua solução resolveu quase que perfeitamente meu problema.
Apenas uma questão... no trecho que você usou "enemy.position" e "transform.position", eu substitui o "position" por "localPosition". Usando somente o "position", o gameObject tinha alguns comportamentos estranhos. Bom... é isso! Muito obrigado e abraços!

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o `transform.eulerAngles`.
essa variável é do tipo `Vector3` e ela pode ser modificada, ela representa a angulação X, Y e Z atual da rotação.

Referência: [Unity Script Reference transform.eulerAngles](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Transform-eulerAngles.html)

Existe também a função `transform.Rotate()`.
a função rotacionará o objeto de acordo com ângulo que você entrar em `Vector3`, e o segundo parâmetro `Space`, que seria a rotação relativa ao espaço.

Referência: [Unity Script Reference transform.Rotate()](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html)

Comment: Obrigado por responder Chinchila!
Bom... eu já tinha analisado essas opções e tive problemas com elas pelo seguinte motivo:
Essas opções, resolveram quando eu tinha uma determinada rotação independente de "alvo" (por isso que citei a função LookAt(Transform), que foca em um alvo).
O que preciso é algo como uma "área de alcance", quando o player estiver nessa área, meu objeto deve focar no player (como uma torre de Tower Defense), do contrário o objeto deve assumir sua posição original.
Já tive lendo algo sobre Quaternions, mais não consegui entender direito. =(
Novamente obrigado e abraços!

Comment: Use um collider para criar hitbox, ae você adiciona ao trigger quando o objeto encostar no campo de colisão ativa a função `LookAt`. A programação do trigger é mais ou menos isso: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html

Comment: Chichila... eu fiz isso, e para falar a verdade esse código ta até comentado porque o LookAt(Transform) mira o eixo Z do GameObject para o "alvo". Isso inevitavelmente rotaciona o eixo X e Y... eu preciso que somente um dos eixos se mova (mais ou menos como o ponteiro de um relógio, que só rotaciona em um eixo), fazendo que meu objeto olhe para o alvo, porém alterando apenas o eixo Y (levando em consideração o posicionamento original do objeto na cena). Abraços e novamente, muito obrigado pela resposta!